# Compilation tidbits on g++, clang++, using libboost -- g++8 compilation fails when g++7 succeeds;

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, clang, travis-ci

I have the code sample on a [github repository](https://github.com/joaomlneto/clang-tidbit) and created a build on [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.com/joaomlneto/clang-tidbit) for easy reproduction.

## Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example

*probably not minimal, but I believe it's small enough*

It creates a shared memory region using the `boost.interprocess` library (`boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory`) and then creates a regular STL `unordered_map` using this regions' allocator from boost library.

The code is a stripped down version from my currently-closed-source library, inspired by the answer in the question [*std::unordered_map with boost::interprocess allocator in shared memory - drawbacks?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49738871/4288486) by [sehe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85371/sehe)

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>

class Thing {
 public:
  volatile Thing *_parent;
  explicit Thing(Thing *parent) : _parent(parent) {}
};

namespace ipc = boost::interprocess;
using Segment = ipc::managed_shared_memory;
using Manager = Segment::segment_manager;
template <typename T> using Alloc = ipc::allocator<T, Manager>;
template <typename K, typename V, typename KH = std::hash<K>, typename KEq = std::equal_to<K>>
using HashMap = std::unordered_map<K, V, KH, KEq, Alloc<void>>;
typedef HashMap<pid_t, Thing> ThingMap;

int main() {
        boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::remove("test");
        Segment my_segment{ipc::create_only, "test", 1ul<<40};
        Manager *my_manager = my_segment.get_segment_manager();
        ThingMap *my_map = my_segment.find_or_construct<ThingMap>("my_map")(my_manager);
        my_map->emplace(123, nullptr);
        printf("Hello world\n");
        return 0;
}
```

## Questions

### 1. `clang++` requires `g++` installed?

Using Ubuntu 14.04, if I install `clang++-6.0` or `clang++-5.0` without updating `g++` (default is version 4.9), I end up with compilation errors.

- [clang 6 without g++](https://travis-ci.com/joaomlneto/clang-tidbit/jobs/140063081)
- [clang 6 with g++](https://travis-ci.com/joaomlneto/clang-tidbit/jobs/140063083)

This is related to not having `libc++` installed and `clang` not installing a c++ library by default and resorting to using what's in the system -- the one bundled with `g++-4.9`?

### 2. Does my code require GNU extensions?

Apparently if I specify `-std=c++17`, it will fail with `g++-8`. However, it will succeed with `g++-7` and `g++-6`.

- g++-8 [with extensions succeeds](https://travis-ci.com/joaomlneto/clang-tidbit/jobs/140063078) VS [without extensions fails](https://travis-ci.com/joaomlneto/clang-tidbit/jobs/140061463)
- g++-7 [with extensions succeeds](https://travis-ci.com/joaomlneto/clang-tidbit/jobs/140063079) VS [without extensions succeeds](https://travis-ci.com/joaomlneto/clang-tidbit/jobs/140061464)
- g++-6 [with extensions succeeds](https://travis-ci.com/joaomlneto/clang-tidbit/jobs/140063080) VS [without extensions succeeds](https://travis-ci.com/joaomlneto/clang-tidbit/jobs/140061465)

Since I was installing `g++-8` in the clang builds, they also fail. My guess is that if I used `g++-7`, they would have succeeded. [Build details with `-std=c++17`](https://travis-ci.com/joaomlneto/clang-tidbit/builds/81896897)

---

Any best-practices advice is greatly appreciated. This is one of my few first attempts in using `clang` in `travis-ci`, or `clang` in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1. `clang++` requires `g++` installed?

No -- but will use whatever standard library is available in the system.

In this case it's because it's an old library version. Installing `libstdc++-8-dev` solves the issue.

## 2. Does my code require GNU extensions?

Yes. As explained to me [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86977) by @jonathan-wakely

> the allocator's value type is not the same as the container's value type (which is exactly what the error tells you!)
>
> GCC will accept it as an extension in `-std=gnu++17` mode, but you compiled with `-std=c++17` which disables the non-standard extension.
>
> > Shouldn't it be also flagged as an error in `gcc-6` and `gcc-7` with `-std=c++17`?
>
> No because the static assertion was only added in `gcc 8`.

The standard way is `using HashMap = std::unordered_map<K, V, KH, KEq, Alloc<std::pair<const K, V>>>;`

- https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86977
- [std::unordered_map with boost::interprocess allocator in shared memory - drawbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49736817/stdunordered-map-with-boostinterprocess-allocator-in-shared-memory-drawbac/49738871#49738871)

(Thanks to @jonathan-wakely for dealing with my noobish questions!)