Boost interprocess throw read access violation
I am using boost's managed_shared_memory, below is the A program which is responsible for creating and constructing an unordered_set.
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include<string>

using namespace boost::interprocess;
const char enrtNdbShareSet[] = "enrtTableSet";
struct EnrtRecord
{
    std::string ern_id = "";
    std::string ern_frequency = "";
    std::string ern_name = "";

    bool operator==(const EnrtRecord& other) const {
        return ern_id == other.ern_id && ern_frequency == other.ern_frequency;
    }

    bool IsKeyNotEmpty() const {
        return ern_id != "" && ern_frequency != "";
    }
};
// hash func
struct EnrtRecordHash
{
    size_t operator()(const EnrtRecord& s) const {
        size_t h1 = boost::hash<std::string>()(s.ern_id);
        size_t h2 = boost::hash<std::string>()(s.ern_frequency);
        return h1 ^ (h2 << 1);
    }
};

using EnrtShmemAllocator = boost::interprocess::allocator<EnrtRecord, boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>;
using EnrtUnorderedSet = boost::unordered_set<EnrtRecord, EnrtRecordHash, std::equal_to<EnrtRecord>, EnrtShmemAllocator>;

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const EnrtRecord& p) {
    os << "enrt_ern_id: " << p.ern_id << ", ern_name: " << p.ern_frequency;
    return os; // 返回ostream对象以支持链式操作  
}

int main()
{
    struct shm_remove
    {
        shm_remove() { shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
        ~shm_remove() { shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
    } remover;
    managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 65536);
    auto mSet = segment.construct<EnrtUnorderedSet>("XX")(3, EnrtRecordHash(), std::equal_to<EnrtRecord>(), segment.get_allocator<EnrtUnorderedSet>());
    EnrtRecord a;
    a.ern_name = "HANGZHOULMM RW25";
    a.ern_id = "AA";
    a.ern_frequency = "444";
    mSet->insert(a);
    while (true) {}
}

the belowing B program is used to read the content in share memory:
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include<string>

using namespace boost::interprocess;
const char enrtNdbShareSet[] = "enrtTableSet";
struct EnrtRecord
{
    std::string ern_id = "";
    std::string ern_frequency = "";
    //std::string ern_mag_var = "";
    std::string ern_name = "";
    bool operator==(const EnrtRecord& other) const {
        return ern_id == other.ern_id && ern_frequency == other.ern_frequency;
    }

    bool IsKeyNotEmpty() const {
        return ern_id != "" && ern_frequency != "";
    }
};
// hash func
struct EnrtRecordHash
{
    size_t operator()(const EnrtRecord& s) const {
        size_t h1 = boost::hash<std::string>()(s.ern_id);
        size_t h2 = boost::hash<std::string>()(s.ern_frequency);
        return h1 ^ (h2 << 1);
    }
};

using EnrtShmemAllocator = boost::interprocess::allocator<EnrtRecord, boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>;
using EnrtUnorderedSet = boost::unordered_set<EnrtRecord, EnrtRecordHash, std::equal_to<EnrtRecord>, EnrtShmemAllocator>;

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const EnrtRecord& p) {
    os << "enrt_ern_id: " << p.ern_id << ", ern_name: " << p.ern_frequency;
    return os; // 返回ostream对象以支持链式操作  
}
int main()
{
    managed_shared_memory segment(open_read_only, "MySharedMemory");


    EnrtUnorderedSet *myGlsset = segment.find<EnrtUnorderedSet>("XX").first;
    for (auto& ele : (*myGlsset)) {
        std::cout << ele << std::endl;
        std::cout<<ele.ern_name << std::endl;
    }
}

but B throw "Exception thrown at 0x75181267 (ucrtbase.dll) in tryINsertSPACE.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00BFFEB8." at std::cout<<ele.ern_name << std::endl;.
However when I change A program with a.ern_name = "HANGZHOULMMRW25",it works fine.Lately I tried a.ern_name = "HANGZHOULMMRW250",it throws exception again, it seems related to the length of string instead of the space problem.

Strings are dynamic containers, just like the set. The small size might mask this fact due to Small String Optimization.
You need to make it use the shared memory allocator to be able to use it. Alternatively, if you can fix the capacity, consider Boost StaticString:
using String = boost::static_string<128>;

See this modernized version of your program:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/static_string.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

using String = boost::static_string<128>;

namespace Enr {
    using boost::hash_value; // enabling ADL
    constexpr auto tableName = "enrtTableSet";

    struct Record {
        String id, frequency, /*mag_var, */ name;

        bool operator==(Record const& other) const = default;
        bool empty() const { return id.empty() && frequency.empty(); }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Record const& rec) {
            return os << "id: " << rec.id                //
                      << " frequency: " << rec.frequency //
                      << " name: " << rec.name;
        }

        friend size_t hash_value(Record const& rec) { return hash_value(std::tie(rec.id, rec.frequency)); }
    };
} // namespace Enr

namespace Shared {
    constexpr auto Name               = "MySharedMemory";
    using Segment                     = bip::managed_shared_memory;
    using Manager                     = Segment::segment_manager;
    template <typename T> using Alloc = bip::allocator<T, Manager>;

    template <typename T, typename H = boost::hash<T>, typename P = std::equal_to<T>>
    using Set = boost::unordered_set<T, H, P, Alloc<T>>;

    void remove() { Segment::device_type::remove(Name); }
}; // namespace Shared

using Set = Shared::Set<Enr::Record>;

void programA() {
    Shared::remove();
    Shared::Segment shm(bip::create_only, Shared::Name, 65536);

    auto& mSet = *shm.construct<Set>(Enr::tableName)(shm.get_segment_manager());
    mSet.insert(Enr::Record{"AA", "444", "HANGZHOULMM RW25"});
    mSet.insert(Enr::Record{"BB", "555", "HANGZHOULMMRW250 more more more more"});
}

void programB() {
    Shared::Segment segment(bip::open_read_only, Shared::Name);

    Set& myGlsset = *segment.find<Set>(Enr::tableName).first;
    for (auto& ele : myGlsset)
        std::cout << ele << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char**) {
    if (argc <= 1)
        programA();
    else
        programB();
}

Testing with
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lrt
./a.out
./a.out B

Prints
id: AA frequency: 444 name: HANGZHOULMM RW25
id: BB frequency: 555 name: HANGZHOULMMRW250 more more more more

Actual Dynamic Strings
They become less convenient because you keep passing allocators around:
Live On Coliru
namespace Shared {
    constexpr auto Name               = "MySharedMemory";
    using Segment                     = bip::managed_shared_memory;
    using Manager                     = Segment::segment_manager;
    template <typename T> using Alloc = bip::allocator<T, Manager>;

    template <typename T, typename H = boost::hash<T>, typename P = std::equal_to<T>>
    using Set    = boost::unordered_set<T, H, P, Alloc<T>>;
    using String = boost::container::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Alloc<char>>;

    void remove() { Segment::device_type::remove(Name); }
}; // namespace Shared

namespace Enr {
    using boost::hash_value; // enabling ADL
    constexpr auto tableName = "enrtTableSet";

    struct Record {
        using allocator_type = Shared::Alloc<char>; // std::uses_allocator protocol

        Record(allocator_type alloc, char const* i, char const* f, char const* n)
            : id(i, alloc)
            , frequency(f, alloc)
            , name(n, alloc) {}

        Shared::String id, frequency, /*mag_var, */ name;

        bool operator==(Record const& other) const = default;
        bool empty() const { return id.empty() && frequency.empty(); }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Record const& rec) {
            return os << "id: " << rec.id                //
                      << " frequency: " << rec.frequency //
                      << " name: " << rec.name;
        }

        friend size_t hash_value(Record const& rec) { return hash_value(std::tie(rec.id, rec.frequency)); }
    };
} // namespace Enr

using Set = Shared::Set<Enr::Record>;

void programA() {
    Shared::remove();
    Shared::Segment shm(bip::create_only, Shared::Name, 65536);
    auto mgr = shm.get_segment_manager();

    auto& mSet = *shm.construct<Set>(Enr::tableName)(mgr);
    mSet.insert(Enr::Record{mgr, "AA", "444", "HANGZHOULMM RW25"});
    mSet.insert(Enr::Record{mgr, "BB", "555", "HANGZHOULMMRW250 more more more more"});
}

With the same output as before.
BONUS: Convenience
Guessing that frequency might actually need to be numeric and using scoped-allocators to alleviate the need to pass around allocators manually:
using Id        = boost::static_string<16>;
using Frequency = double;
using Name      = Shared::String;

Now the advantage of the uses_allocator protocol comes to light:
mSet.emplace("AA", 444, "HANGZHOULMM RW25");
mSet.emplace("BB", 555, "HANGZHOULMMRW250 more more more more");

See it Live On Coliru
#include <boost/container/scoped_allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/container/string.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/static_string.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

namespace Shared {
    namespace bc = boost::container;

    constexpr auto ShmName   = "MySharedMemory";
    using Segment                     = bip::managed_shared_memory;
    using Manager                     = Segment::segment_manager;
    template <typename T> using Alloc = bc::scoped_allocator_adaptor<bip::allocator<T, Manager>>;

    template <typename T, typename H = boost::hash<T>, typename P = std::equal_to<T>>
    using Set       = boost::unordered_set<T, H, P, Alloc<T>>;
    using String    = bc::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Alloc<char>>;

    void remove() { Segment::device_type::remove(ShmName); }
}; // namespace Shared

namespace Enr {
    using Id        = boost::static_string<16>;
    using Frequency = double;
    using Name      = Shared::String;

    constexpr auto tableName = "enrtTableSet";
    using boost::hash_value; // enabling ADL

    struct Record {
        using allocator_type = Name::allocator_type; // std::uses_allocator protocol

        Record(char const* i = "", Frequency f = {}, char const* n = "", allocator_type alloc = {})
            : id(i)
            , frequency(f)
            , name(n, alloc) {}

        Id        id;
        Frequency frequency;
        Name      name;

        bool operator==(Record const& other) const = default;
        bool empty() const { return id.empty() && frequency == Frequency{}; }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Record const& rec) {
            return os << "id: " << rec.id                //
                      << " frequency: " << rec.frequency //
                      << " name: " << rec.name;
        }

        friend size_t hash_value(Record const& rec) { return hash_value(std::tie(rec.id, rec.frequency)); }
    };
} // namespace Enr

using Set = Shared::Set<Enr::Record>;

void programA() {
    Shared::remove();
    Shared::Segment shm(bip::create_only, Shared::ShmName, 65536);

    auto& mSet = *shm.construct<Set>(Enr::tableName)(shm.get_segment_manager());
    mSet.emplace("AA", 444, "HANGZHOULMM RW25");
    mSet.emplace("BB", 555, "HANGZHOULMMRW250 more more more more");
}

void programB() {
    Shared::Segment segment(bip::open_read_only, Shared::ShmName);

    Set& myGlsset = *segment.find<Set>(Enr::tableName).first;
    for (auto& ele : myGlsset)
        std::cout << ele << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char**) {
    if (argc <= 1)
        programA();
    else
        programB();
}

Again with similar output:
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lrt
./a.out
./a.out B
id: AA frequency: 444 name: HANGZHOULMM RW25
id: BB frequency: 555 name: HANGZHOULMMRW250 more more more more


Thank you sehe very much for your answier, I learned a lot and it is very helpful to me

Hi，sehe，I use the static_string to solve the problem in my work code. Dynamic string can't compile Because Enr Record comes from access database. First., I need to store all these records in a std::vector(This maybe cause the failure).Then I need to choose some records from the vector to update the share memory dynamically according some condition. I tried dynamic string, it failed.I want to use dynamic string. what can i do.

"Because Enr Record comes from access database" seems like an unnecessary problem. I can write database code that creates Enr records just fine. If that's somehow not convenient you will have to make a trade-off where you interconvert the two. I have some related answers on this site like e.g.  the two examples listed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51439056/85371

Thank you, sehe, it's very helpful to me
